# Reference request for ${\rm Out}(SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p))$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm looking for an english, ideally relatively modern reference for the fact that the outer automorphism group of $SL(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ is order $2$ (for $p$ odd), generated by conjugation by an element of $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ of nonsquare determinant.

Other references would also be nice.

If anyone has a nice looking pdf of Dieudonne's "La geometrie des groupes classiques" that would be nice as well. I can only find a poorly scanned djvu version.

Comment: Are you only looking for a reference, or would a direct proof answer your question as well? If the latter, this should be rather straightforwards by some Sylow theory, and including this as a proposition in whatever your writing might be acceptable. (As far as the part of the question asking for a scanned copy of the book, asking for things like this here is probably a little questionable - your best bet is to go ask your local librarian to get you a copy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One place where what you are asking about appears explicitly is Robert Wilson's book "The Finite Simple Groups", page 50:

[image]